# Set cache-control for specific file/folder in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cache-control

In a 5.2.9 spring project with

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

in webmvc-config.xml. Static images are served with the `cache-control: /*omissions */ no-cache` header. I'm trying to override this header for specific files or folder.

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**">
    <mvc:cache-control max-age="3600" cache-public="true"/>
</mvc:resources>
```

If I replace with the above it works as I want but it targets all files. I've tried to be more specific like:

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/myImages/**">
    <mvc:cache-control max-age="3600" cache-public="true"/>
</mvc:resources>
```

But I do not think it likes having two resources tags? I do not see a clear way in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-caching) to do what I want, but I'm not very familiar with the domain. I do not think I want an 'interceptor'?